# OGC webservice engine like geoserver in .NET

Tags: arcgis-engine, .net, ogc, ogcserver

In java there are a lots of third part libraries which can used to create OGC webserivce like wcs/wfs/wms etc.

However I have not found anything similar in .NET.

We are currently using ArcGIS Engine, but it ArcGIS Engine does not support web applications.

Is there a alternative?

Comment: Did you look at MapWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only option you have, is ArcGIS Server. And its OGC webservices just feel like a second though, to its own webservices.

Generally speaking, the type of people who believe  in the FOSS movement, tend to work in Java/PHP etc rather than .NET. Hence there are very few successful Open Source projects in .NET.

Comment: Not entirely bourne out by the facts. Sourceforge has about ~2700 Windows projects that use C#. That's more than there are Python projects and only slightly less than C. PHP has just 500 more. However some communities are better supported by spatial libraries than others.

Comment: Just 2700 out of 300000 projects?

Comment: No. 2700 out of ~30,000. Java, the clear winner is at only 7,700. - I was using this search: http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/ - and the numbers are from the drop-down. So only checking recent projects and only for Windows. Remove the Windows requirement and the total number only goes up to about 35,000.